# How to declare a datetime variable with null value

Tags: powershell

How I create a `datetime`, `int` variables with initializing then to `null`, I try this but it shows error

```
[datetime] $var1 = $null
```

Error:

```
WARNING: Error: Cannot convert value "var1" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) is a .NET [*value type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types), so you cannot set a variable of that type to `$null` - you can only set it to `0` in this case:

```
[datetime] $var1 = 0
```

If you do need the variable to contain `$null`, you have two options:

- Do *not* type-constrain it (no type literal (`[...]`) to the left of the variable name):

```
$var1 = $null
```

- Type-constrain it as a *nullable* value type:

```
[Nullable[datetime]] $var1 = $null
```

Comment: Thanks this works but I cant use same approach while creating object. ` $obj_var=New-Object psobject -Property @{[nullable[datetime]]"var1" = $null}` . Could you please help with this also.

Comment: @sql_dummy You cannot type-constrain properties in `[pscustomobject]` instances (do not use `[psobject]`); without a type constraint, use `$obj_var = [pscustomobject] @{ var1  = $null }`. If you do need to type-constrain properties, you must define a PSv5+ custom `class`. If you need further assistance, please ask a _new_ question. Given that this answer addresses your question _as asked_, please consider accepting it.